# Where can I pull the server host name from if we can't store it in this script?

Tags: bash, github, jenkins, gemfire

I noticed someone creating a bunch of scripts to run on GemFire clusters, where they have multiple copies of the same script where the only difference between the scripts is the server name.

Here is a picture of the Github repo

[image: screen shot of our GitHub repo for scripts]

What the script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /sys_data/gemfire/scripts/gf-common.env
#----------------------------------------------------------
# Start the servers
#----------------------------------------------------------
(ssh -n <SERVER_HOST_NAME_HERE> ". ${GF_INST_HOME}/scripts/gfsh-server.sh gf_cache1 start")
```

`SERVER_HOST_NAME_HERE` = the IP address or server name that the script was designed for, removed for the purposes of this questions.

I would like to create one script with a parameter for the server name. Problem is: **I'm not exactly sure where the best location would be to store/retrieve the server ip/host name(s), and let the script reference it, any ideas?** The number of cache servers will vary depending on environment, application, and cluster.

Our development pipeline should work like this ideally:

1. Users commit a file to GitHub repo
2. Triggers Jenkins job
3. Jenkins job copies file to each cache server, shuts down that server using the `stop_cache.sh` script, then runs the `start_cache.sh` script. The number of cache servers can vary from cluster to cluster.
4. GemFire cache servers are updated with new file.

Comment: Dns would be a classic solution for this problem. You are basically asking how do to service discovery.

Comment: Right now you have them hardcoded in each file it seems. So extract them to a separate file(s), loop through entries in that file and run `for host in $(cat cache_hostnames.txt) ; ./stop_cache.sh $host ; done` and something similar for other kinds of services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with the method suggested by @nos

> Right now you have them hardcoded in each file it seems. So extract them to a separate file(s), loop through entries in that file and run for host in $(cat cache_hostnames.txt) ; ./stop_cache.sh $host ; done and something similar for other kinds of services?

Placed the server names in a file, and looped through the file.

Answer (score -1):

This project might be of interest:

https://github.com/Pivotal-Data-Engineering/gemfire-manager